# Jsonpath for a JSON payload

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have the following JSON payload. I would like to extract the value "value_for_key_attribute_Y" using JSON path expression in a generic manner (i.e. without hard coding any array values like [1]) Any ideas ?

```
{  
   "requests":[  
      {  
         "event":[  
            {  
               "parameter":"parameter_key_A",
               "event":"event_key_A",
            }
         ],
         "data":[  
            {  
               "id":"id_xyz",
               "payload_data":[  
                  {  
                     "key":"key_attribute_X",
                    "value":"value_for_key_attribute_X",
                  },
                  {  
                     "key":"key_attribute_Y",
                     "value":"value_for_key_attribute_Y",
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.

```
$.requests[*].data[*].payload_data[?(@.key_path == 'key_attribute_Y')].value
```